# Apache reverse proxy "Failed to load resource" 502 Proxy Error

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

### Background

As the path of least resistance on getting my Web app (served by AllegroServe) to deal with a potential partner's Shibboleth SOS setup I decided to try running Apache in front of AllegroServe, since the partner and Shibboleth support Apache.

Anyway, I took a dead simple approach and just dropped this in httpd.conf after turning on all the recommended modules for reverse proxy:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000 retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=3000 Keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000
```

All the options on ProxyPass were added based on something I googled up, but timeout seems not to be the problem because this error comes back in a few milliseconds: "failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Proxy Error)" on this bit of HTML in (the only thing that does load) the index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/soa.js"></script>
```

I also tried just loading an image and get the same error, and I put the image in the same directory as index.html in case it was a directory access issue.

I note, FWIW, that the request for soa.js or the image does not make it to AllegroServe (or at least it does not log anything).

btw, AllegroServe is running on port 8000 and I can access localhost:8000 without a problem. And to repeat myself, hitting localhost:8080 works as far as loading the index.html.

I have checked permissions on the directories in question but suspect that is not the issue since it is getting to the index.html (and, again, the follow-up request for the JS (or png file) do not seem even to be reaching AllegroServe.

Answer (score 25):

Need a slash (see after the 8000) to indicate the path is a wildcard so the whole tree is in play:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=3000 Keepalive=On 
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
```

-kt